# how to correct errors identified by valgrind?

Tags: c++, valgrind

I am trying to use valgrind to clear up some code and I cannot seem to figure out how to correct some of the errors it has identified. What is wrong with this:

```
 std::string sLog = parseString( ... );
 m_sVideoCapLogFile.append(sLog);
```

Isn't the sLog string cleaned up when it leaves the scope of {}  ?
I have tried to call the dtor for sLog like this:

sLog.std::string::~string();

But that doesn't work plus it just seems wrong to have to do that.
Valgrind flags this as:

97 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 7 of 7

how do I clean this up?

Thanks,
-Andres

Comment: How are you sure it's not something else near that code that is causing the leak?

Comment: `sLog.std::string::~string();`  - don't do that. Instead, make a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post that.

Comment: I am not sure it is something else near that code. That is the reason why I am using valgrind to try to clean up everything that looks suspicious. valgrind reports so many errors that it becomes very hard to know what is the real problems and what I should ignore. I am working on the suppressions now. I figure valgrind knows more than I do so I want my code to pass its scrutiny.

Comment: In most cases valgrind is too good to be supressed. While given code doesn't look wrong, it is quite likely to be caused by memory stomping. What is 97 bytes here? Is it length of string buffer (e.g. `length` or `capacity`)? If you'll set string to constant instead of calling `parseString`, will message persist? Opposite, what happens if you'll comment `append`? That should give you direction on where to look (although with corrupt memory it might not be the right one).